# Wrong data in query, Laravel

Tags: laravel, postgresql, maatwebsite-excel

I try to export some data in excel using `Maatwebsite\Excel`. Also from front-end I pass some params ,and the problem is that in `dd()` I get correct data, but in excel file I get wrong data (usually nothing or all rows from db.)

**My `__construct()`:**

```php
    public function __construct($req) {
        $this->request= $req;
     }
```

**The query:**

```php
    public function query()
        {
            $direction = ($this->request->sort_direction === 'false') ? 'asc' : 'desc';

            $query = ViewData::query();


            if ($this->request->has('search_gender') && !is_null($this->request->search_gender)) {
                $query->where('gender', '=', $this->request->search_gender );
            }
            // HERE I get some strange things..
            // ($this->request->search_gender === "F")  -> if I use "F", works, if I use $this->request->search_gender , don't!
            // also if I use $this->request->search_gender, in dd($query->get()); I get correct data, in excel file I get wrong data


            if(!$this->request->sort_by){
                $this->request->sort_by = "full_name";
            }

            $query->orderBy($this->request->sort_by, $direction);

            return $query;
        }
```

**My controller:**

```php
    //  Export CSV data
    public function export(Request $request) 
    {
        return (new DataExport($request))->download('data.xlsx');
    }
```

**Update with actual query:**

```php
     array:3 [

              "query" => "select * from "view_full_data" where "gender" = ? order by "full_name" desc"
              "bindings" => array:1 [
                0 => "M"
              ]
              "time" => 34.7
            ]
```

Comment: Can you put more information in how do you create your excel file? Or the function that manipulates the data on your file creation?

Comment: I just added the controller and __construct , I hope that helps.

Comment: About the `$request` variable in `export()` function? when you call the `new DataExport()`, gets in the right way?

Comment: Yes, if I dd($this->request) //I get what I need. I also try request() , without passing from controller. Like:     public function __construct() {    $this->data = request();  }  , I get data, but in my query I get " ? " ..

Comment: Maybe is not a type problem? `F` can be interpreted as `FALSE`. With `M`, the query works well? And, if you get `dd($this->request->search_gender)`, what you get and, what type you get when you select `F`?

Comment: No, in my where(), I can't pass any var...not sure why. even an $test = "test" , in my query is null..

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT 1: Following `Maatwebsite\Excel` documentation:**

Reading the documentation, I believe that I understood your `query()` call. That is a `implements` from  `InvoicesExport`.

As following the official [documentation](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/from-query.html), I believe that you need to create a constructor parameter to use in your `where`. Follow the doc example:

```
namespace App\Exports;

use App\Invoice;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromQuery;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;

class InvoicesExport implements FromQuery
{
    use Exportable;

    public function __construct(int $year)
    {
        $this->year = $year;
    }

    public function query()
    {
        return Invoice::query()->whereYear('created_at', $this->year);
    }
}
```

And export your data as follows:

```
return (new InvoicesExport(2018))->download('invoices.xlsx');
```

---

**ORIGINAL:**

If I understood the problem, could be this:

The  `?` is a binded value.

If you see in your dump:

```
"bindings" => array:1 [
    0 => "M"
]
```

You think that your query will parse this value and substitute your `?` with the respective value.

If you want to get your raw sql, try this:

`dd($query->toSql());`

And you can see if that your binding value will be parsed. And you can check if the query are built in the right way.

Comment: Yes. that's exactly the case, but I am not sure how to get that value in my query..

Comment: I saw this, too. still no good. If helps: https://codeshare.io/5e6OWJ , this is the full current code..